# Как заставить setInterval срабатывать на определенное количество секунд раньше другого интервала

Tags: javascript, css, css3, setinterval

Есть контейнер, в котором каждые 5 секунд меняется содержимое.

```
setInterval(changeCard, 5000)
setInterval(changeCard1, 10000)
function changeCard(){
  first.innerHTML = 'содержимое контейнера'
}

function changeCard1(){
  first.innerHTML = 'содержимое контейнера'
}
```

К этому изменению нужно добавить плавности, сделал это так

```
.op1{
  opacity: 0%;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

function op(){
  first.classList.toggle('op1')
}
function op1(){
  first.classList.toggle('op1')
}

setInterval(op, 4800)
setInterval(op1, 5000)
```

За 200мс до изменения содержимого блока, он плавно становиться прозрачным, а после сразу проявляется с уже новым содержимым, но из-за того что мс 4800, следующий раз оно срабатывает не как нужно - за 200мс до смены содержимого, а через 9600, что уже 400мс.

Как можно это реализовать чтобы класс каждый раз добавлялся и удалялся именно за 200мс до смены, а не через 4800мс после запуска кода

Comment: Изучите тему промисов  https://learn.javascript.ru/promise   а можно сразу async/await https://learn.javascript.ru/async-await   и используйте их в своём коде

Comment: а вообще можно сделать так, чтобы удаление класса было прописано как setINterval внутри первой функции для добавления класса и всё

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: но насчет второго не понял, как это решит проблему нецелого числа?

Comment: Что ещё за проблема нецелого числа?

Comment: 4800   ||    за 200мс до изменения содержимого блока, он плавно становиться прозрачным, а после сразу проявляется с уже новым содержимым, но из-за того что мс 4800, следующий раз оно срабатывает не как нужно - за 200мс до смены содержимого, а через 9600, что уже 400мс.     если просто удалять внутри интервалом 4800 никуда не девается и проблема остается прежней

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для достижения нужного эффекта, я бы предложил использовать setTimeout

setInterval будет вызывать функцию каждые 5000 мс, которая запускает setTimeout с таймером в 4800мс, таким образом, установка нужного вам класса будет происходить за +/-200мс до смены контента.

```js
let v = 1;
const text = 'текст';
const first = document.getElementById('first');

function visual() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    first.classList.toggle('op1');
  }, 4800);
}

function op() {
  first.classList.toggle('op1');
  v++;
  first.innerText = `${text} ${v}`;
  visual();
}

setInterval(op, 5000);
visual();
```

```css
.op1 {
  opacity: 0%;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<div id="first">
  текст 1
</div>
```

Такого же эффекта можно достичь промисами:

```js
let v = 1;
const text = 'текст';
const first = document.getElementById('first');

// Функция сна
function sleep(time) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, time);
  })
}

async function op() {
  await sleep(4800) // Ждем 4800
    .then(() => { // потом
      first.classList.toggle('op1'); // ставим класс
      sleep(200).then(() => { // ждем еще 200 
        first.classList.toggle('op1'); // убираем класс
        v++;
        first.innerText = `${text} ${v}`; // Меняем текст
        op();
      })
    })
}

op();
```

```css
.op1 {
  opacity: 0%;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<div id="first">
  текст 1
</div>
```

Comment: большое спасибо, то что нужно было